# How to select rows that doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table amounts:

```
department|account|month|amount 
a         |x      |1    |100
a         |x      |2    |100
a         |x      |3    |100
a         |x      |4    |100
a         |x      |5    |100
a         |x      |6    |100
a         |x      |7    |100
a         |x      |8    |100
a         |x      |9    |100
a         |x      |10   |100
a         |x      |11   |100
a         |x      |12   |100
b         |x      |2    |300
```

And this table accounting_period:

```
month|
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

What I would like is this:

```
department|account|month|amount
a         |x      |1    |100
a         |x      |2    |100
a         |x      |3    |100
a         |x      |4    |100
a         |x      |5    |100
a         |x      |6    |100
a         |x      |7    |100
a         |x      |8    |100
a         |x      |9    |100
a         |x      |10   |100
a         |x      |11   |100
a         |x      |12   |100

b         |x      |1    |0
b         |x      |2    |300
b         |x      |3    |0
b         |x      |4    |0
b         |x      |5    |0
b         |x      |6    |0
b         |x      |7    |0
b         |x      |8    |0
b         |x      |9    |0
b         |x      |10   |0
b         |x      |11   |0
b         |x      |12   |0
```

I can join the two tables with this select:

```
select department,account,A.month,sum(b.AMOUNT) amount
from accounting_period A
left join amounts B on A.month=B.MONTH 

where B.DEPARTMENT in ('a','b')
and b.account='x'
group by month,account,department
```

But that gives me only this result.
How can I get all months for department b showing up without 0 amount?

```
MONTH ACCOUNT DEPARTMENT BUDGET
1     x       a          100
2     x       a          100
3     x       a          100
3     x       b          300
4     x       a          100
5     x       a          100
6     x       a          100
7     x       a          100
8     x       a          100
9     x       a          100
10    x       a          100
11    x       a          100
12    x       a          100
```

Comment: which database server do you use?

Comment: It's an Oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of `accounting_period` to the distinct values of `department` and `account` of `amounts` and then a `LEFT` join to `amounts`:

```
select d.department, d.account, ap.month, coalesce(a.amount, 0) amount
from accounting_period ap 
cross join (select distinct department, account from amounts where department in ('a','b')) d
left join amounts a
on ap.month = a.month and d.department = a.department and d.account = a.account
order by d.department, d.account, ap.month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9ae58400fcf898fa1d307ae6e379b4b5).
Results:

```
> DEPARTMENT | ACCOUNT | MONTH | AMOUNT
> :--------- | :------ | ----: | -----:
> a          | x       |     1 |    100
> a          | x       |     2 |    100
> a          | x       |     3 |    100
> a          | x       |     4 |    100
> a          | x       |     5 |    100
> a          | x       |     6 |    100
> a          | x       |     7 |    100
> a          | x       |     8 |    100
> a          | x       |     9 |    100
> a          | x       |    10 |    100
> a          | x       |    11 |    100
> a          | x       |    12 |    100
> b          | x       |     1 |      0
> b          | x       |     2 |    300
> b          | x       |     3 |      0
> b          | x       |     4 |      0
> b          | x       |     5 |      0
> b          | x       |     6 |      0
> b          | x       |     7 |      0
> b          | x       |     8 |      0
> b          | x       |     9 |      0
> b          | x       |    10 |      0
> b          | x       |    11 |      0
> b          | x       |    12 |      0
```

Comment: I got it to work using a cross join and the level solution from @Barbaros Özhan. But using a cross join makes everything run too slow, so I droped it for now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

One option would be using a **partition by join**.

A side node: **accounting_period** table is redundant, might be replaced with hierarchical query in order to generate rows for months of a year. Kindly change it.

```
with mons as
(
    select level mnts
    from dual connect by level <= 12
)
select department, account, mnts as month, nvl(amount,0) as amount
  from amounts a partition by ( department, account ) 
 right join mons m
    on a.month = m.mnts
 order by department, account, mnts;
```

Comment: Month is not a reserved word for Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: very nice solution, congratulations !